# How can I get Socket.io to connect again?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

In my Node.js backend I have the following code which is supposed to set up the Socket.io connection:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { createServer } = require("http");
const httpServer = createServer(app);

const port = 3001;
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, { cors: { origin: "*" } });

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("Connected!");
    
    socket.on("join-room", (id) => {
        socket.join(id);
        console.log(`user joined room ${id}`);
    });
});
```

Previously this was working, but for some reason it isn't anymore. When I started my server today I wasn't able to get `Connected!` logged to the console, nor was `user joined room` logged to the console when that event was triggered. Is there something wrong with how I'm establishing this connection?

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure but i see that you created httpServer without listening on it,  (you did not execute the `.listen(port)` function) i guess

Comment: That was it. I guess the socket has to listen on a different port than the server then? I changed it so the socket is on port 3002 and the server is on 3001 and it works now.

Comment: socket.io does NOT have to listen on a different port from your http server - they can share the same server on the same port just fine (it was all designed to be able to do that).   But, you do have to start you http server before it's functional which your code does not show.  You create an http server, but never start it.

Comment: yes exactly, as @jfriend00 said, you can use the same port and just have to listen on that port by starting your server